# Incorrect date obtained after processing

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I run the following code and obtain incorrect date (instead of 1/2/2015  6:00:00 AM it prints 12/28/2015  6:00:00 AM):

```
    SimpleDateFormat _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/YYYY  H:mm:ss a");
    _time = "02/01/2015  6:00:00 AM";
    Date date;
    try {
        date = _sdf.parse(_time);
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        _time = _sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(_time);  // 12/28/2015  6:00:00 AM   !!!
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually get all the way to `_sdf.format()`? I think `setTime()` does not swallow anything but an instance of `Date`.

Comment: `YYYY` != `yyyy`, basically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy  H:mm:ss a");
```

i.e, you need to use yyyy instead if YYYY.

Check the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks so much!